# How to Change Netbeans Fonts and Colors Preview Document?

Tags: netbeans, colors, fonts

Within the Netbeans 6.5's Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Syntax dialog, you have the ability to change the look and feel of the Netbeans text editor. When you select a language, you are presented with a preview of your font/color scheme. However, when I preview Java, there are far more options for syntax changes than are being displayed in that preview window. If I were able to view a more robust piece of code, I'd be able to see the immediate effect of more of the options.

How can I supply a preview document to view my font/color changes?

UPDATE:

After looking into this some more, I've been able to narrow down the problem a bit. From what I can tell, everything in Netbeans is considered a plugin. The GUI editor is a plugin, and even the text editor is a plugin. This means that what ever piece of Netbeans that actually analyzes Java code and does syntax highlights is also a plugin (since Java is just one of many languages Netbeans highlights, it makes sense this is a plugin).

I think fromvega is on the right track with his suggestion. The tutorial for creating a manifest file editing plugin pointed me in the right direction. The tutorial eludes to a file used as a sample document used for font/color previews. It tells you how to create one inside this new plugin project. (Located in "Registering the Options in the NetBeans System Filesystem", part 4. About 4/5 of the way down the page.)

My next line of thought was to look for the Java syntax editing mode plugin and find this file and update it with a richer example file. I looked in the installation directory and came up empty, but I found what looks like the appropriate files within my user settings directory. There is a config directory with a lot of subfolders within my user directory (Windows: C:\Documents and Settings\saterus.netbeans\config).

I've been poking around inside this directory a bit, but have only found the xml files the manifest tutorial talks about. I have been unable to find the extensionless sample file for the Java plugin that I believe should be there.

Since I've hit a brick wall for the moment, I thought I'd toss it back to the SO community and see if you guys might make the last leap and find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document which is displayed (for each mime type) is specified in a particular folder in the "system file system" (which is a NetBeans concept which is a virtual file system composed from contributions from individual modules; this is how functionality is dynamically registered in NetBeans).

Modules typically specify their system file system contributions in a file named "layer.xml" in the plugin. The create plugin templates typically offer to create this for you.

For example, here's how the Python example is registered:

```
<filesystem>
    ...
    <folder name="OptionsDialog">
        <folder name="PreviewExamples">
            <folder name="text">
                <file name="x-python" url="PythonExample.py"/>
            </folder>
        </folder>
        ...
```

Here, PythonExample.py is a sample file in the same directory as the layer file.

Therefore, what you need to do is create a plugin which overrides the existing registration(s) for the mime type(s) you care about and provide alternate sample documents. You may need to hide the existing registration first (see the _hidden
part from http://doc.javanb.com/netbeans-api-javadoc-5-0-0/org-openide-filesystems/org/openide/filesystems/MultiFileSystem.html ).

Hopefully this guides you in the right direction.

However, in thinking about it, we probably ought to make the preview area editable - so people can cut & paste whatever codefragment they care about right in there. This wouldn't be persistent, so whenever you change languages you get the original samples back - but it provides a quick way to see your own code. This shouldn't be just for the Fonts & Colors customization, but for the Formatting preview panels as well.

I've filed an issue against NetBeans for this:
http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=155964

-- Tor

Answer (score 4):

Just for anyone who wants to alter this themselves it is possible on a unix machine to use grep to locate the file i.e.

```
grep -lr "some part of the current sample code" /path/to/netbeans
```

I used this method to locate the ruby example filename and from that identified that it is kept in org-netbeans-modules-ruby.jar as a file called RubyExample. By simply altering that file I was able to construct a better sample file for my own use.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, thanks! I have no interest in going through the round-about way mentioned in the accepted answer and original question, even if this will get overridden the next time I update Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only accomplish that with a new plugin, since you need somekind of parsing to define what is what.

Give a look a these tutorials, I haven't read them in details but they seem to show you how to do what you want:

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-mfsyntax.html
http://www.antonioshome.net/kitchen/netbeans/nbms-coloring.php

Comment: I don't think that was the question. He was looking at the dialog for changing syntax coloring and seeing that some items (e.g. "Local variable declaration") do not appear in the sample document (it's a bit of Java, but there are no local variables). He's wondering how to change the sample document.

Comment: So as I previous said, I think that to change the sample document one would need to put his hands into some code.

Comment: Are you sure the code preview dialog isn't using the normal Netbeans parser? The Netbeans editor has a Java parser that can fully recognize what is considered syntax and what is not. I assumed the code preview would simply use this, rather than define its own parser.